# Displaying JSON variable value in Laravel

Tags: arrays, json, laravel

I have received this, in my recent Laravel 4.1 project which I believe a JSON return,

```
{"id":5,"owner":"2","message":"What a wonderful shoot today in Belgium!","post_at":"2","created_at":"2014-02-25 15:05:50","updated_at":"2014-02-25 19:05:50"}
```

however I usually able to display it like this:

```
echo $post->id;
```

but somehow instead of "5", it's returning nothing. 
but when I converted to array using `$post->toArray();` and trying to view using `echo $post['id'];` it successfully returns "5".

What's the best way to be able to return it's value using `echo $post->id;`? I also have tried to ensure the variable as JSON by using `$post->toJSON();` but it still returns empty.

Comment: Why is it being returned as JSON if you want to access it like an object? That being said, since it's JSON, `json_decode`, is what you're looking for: http://php.net/json_decode. That will convert the JSON to a stdClass object.

Comment: Awesome. It worked well! I got the JSON from a costume model class with query 
`static::whereIn('owner', $meandfriends)->orderby('updated_at','desc')->get()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this

```
$post = Post::where('id','=',5)->get()
```

(not forget **get()** )

or

```
$post = Post::where('id',5)->get()
```

(not forget **get()** )

or

```
$post = Post::find(5);
```

Response maybe:

```
Response::json($post);
```

Comment: You're query is tested and it worked, but it's not what I meant, however thanks I realized it now, I should've return like this:


`if(!is_null($stream = static::whereIn('owner', $meandfriends)->orderby('updated_at','desc')->get())){
         return json_decode($stream);
        }
     `

instead of:

`if(!is_null($stream = static::whereIn('owner', $meandfriends)->orderby('updated_at','desc')->get())){
         return $stream;
        }`

Answer (score 0):

```
   $.get('url', {'id': id}, function (obj) {
     var te=obj.id;
     alert(te);
   });
```

Comment: He wants to do it right in the template, not with jQuery.